# How to build the EDM model for the OData service which having return type of KeyValuePair

Tags: odata

Post Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public Dictionary<string, object> PostData(ODataActionParameters param)
{     
}
```

To Build EDM Model:

```
 ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
 var customSave = builder.EntityType<Model>().Collection.Action("PostData");
```

How to set the return of an action "customSave"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
 var customSave = builder.EntityType<Model>().Collection.Action("PostData");
 customSave.ReturnsCollection<Dictionary<string, object>>();
```

To establish the return type of the Action used when the return type is a collection of either Primitive or ComplexTypes.